# Android canvas not updating

Tags: java, android

I have a GameView.java class and inside it I have

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 0, 0));
            canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, 
paint);
        }
    }
```

but when I run the program i still get a completely black screen. Why might this be?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqA2u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the instance variables or methods of a class cannot be invoked without an instance. In this case, you are trying to access instance variables/methods of the class paddle. You have 2 options,

1. Instead of calling `paddle.setMovementState()`,

   `paddle mypaddle = new paddle(x,y);
   myPaddle.setMovementState(myPaddle.STOPPED);`
2. Alternatively you can change variables and methods in paddle to static. For example,

   `public static final int RIGHT = 2;`

Ideally you should have your methods as non-static (option 1) above and your constants as static (option 2).

Comment: Doesn't this just work for one direction in my code?